# java Mask Ip address

Tags: java, regex, string, mask

I want to write a java program to mask specific ip addresses in the input string

for e.g.

```
String input = "AAA192.10.*BBB10.92.*"
```

Requirement : Ip address to mask is `10.*` so it should mask all ip addresses that start with `10.`

So output should be `AAA192.10.*BBBYYYYYYY`  (It replaced each character of `10.92.*` with `Y`)

I need to match the regex `10.*` to match all ip addresses which start with `10.`

Comment: The input...seems weird to me.  What is it really trying to denote?

Comment: The input consist of string alongwith ip addresses. i need to parse the input string and need to mask specific ip address with some character.

Comment: Your question is not clear. I don't know what you define as "mask" and what's your expected input / output

Comment: I just want to remove specific ip-address from input string and stuff some character at that location.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do IP with regex.  You'll almost always get it wrong.  Even when you have the possibility of getting it right, it is in such small corner cases as to render the entire exercise pointless.

For example, what is the regex to mask 192.168.128.0/15?  Remember that with this pattern, 192.168.120.35 and 192.168.129.35 are in different networks.

It gets worse with /14, /13, /12, etc.

The folks over at OpenNMS did something similar to what you are doing some time back, although they implemented their "network matcher" as a PostgreSQL function.  It had to be rewritten a few times to take it away from it's regex roots and into the modern world.  It caused more issues than it fixed.

Since you have Java already available, use the Java networking classes.  They are far more robust than any regex solution you could cobble together.  For example, you could look at how to determine if two addresses are in the same network.

```
public static boolean sameNetwork(InetAddress ip1, InetAddress ip2, String mask) 
throws Exception {

    byte[] a1 = ip1.getAddress();
    byte[] a2 = ip2.getAddress();
    byte[] m = InetAddress.getByName(mask).getAddress();

    for (int i = 0; i < a1.length; i++)
        if ((a1[i] & m[i]) != (a2[i] & m[i]))
            return false;

    return true;

}
```

(credit to Óscar López) for this snippet

Any attempt to do the same with regex is going to be far larger and far less likely to be correct.